# How to get total bytes count transferred over the connection with libcurl?

Tags: c++, sockets, libcurl

Libcurl allows to get information how much bytes application level protocol (HTTP, FTP, etc) sent and received. However, is there any way to get amount of bytes that *underlying socket* sent and received? I am about all data, including, for example, bytes that socket used to establish SSL connection. So, I am basically searching a way to get the same information from libcurl that Apache HTTP client gives in `HttpConnectionMetrics.getSentBytesCount()` and `HttpConnectionMetrics.getReceivedBytesCount()`.
One idea is to access socket that Libcurl uses directly from C++; however, how to get this socket total sent/received bytes count?

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is not avaiable in cURL, you have to count the bytes for each transfer, using some other mechanisms.

Comment: May be, but what mechanisms are available? The problem is that `libcurl` and `openssl` both use the same socket, so probably the only solution is to intercept the traffic on TCP lelel somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION.html) and just add up the different parts, as it shows the socket level amounts. This will thus give you an exact number for all protocols speaking plain-text, those not using SSL

**However** - that won't necessarily give you the counters for the SSL level stuff though in case of HTTPS/FTPS etc, as libcurl doesn't always expose that. It depends on what particular TLS backend it was built to use. The OpenSSL backend should be fine and it will tell you about incoming and outgoing TLS data too (using the same debug callback).

Comment: What exactly in my answer doesn't explain that? For HTTP you'll get it exact, for SSL based protocols like HTTPS you'll get it exact if libcurl was built against OpenSSL. Where's the error?

Comment: Thanks, Daniel, this answer is what I search.